# invalid distance too far back

Tags: java, apache, compression

I'm using `org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.deflate.DeflateCompressorInputStream;` and error `invalid distance too far back`is occured. I don't know what this error means. Exists some documentation for that ? Or any solution how to repair that.

Comment: I did a google search and it came up https://www.google.com/search?q=invalid%20distance%20too%20far%20back&cad=h

Answer (score 1):

It means that the input is either corrupted, or that it isn't deflate compressed data in the first place.